# Scale the x axis only in octave plot

Tags: octave

I am using the Octave plot function to plat a 2D graph.  I want to scale the x axis by 2x (no change to y axis).  i.e. the distance between each unit in x axis is doubled.

How do I do that in Octave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the parameter "dataaspectratio" of the function "set" to modify the aspect ratio of the plot (as the self explaining parameter name indicates). dataaspectratio accepts a 3-element vector, with the scales for X,Y and Z, so if you want X to be double as the Y axis scale you should use:

```
set(gca,'dataaspectratio',[2 1 1])
```